# PHP Blenc error unable to read stream, compiling with default compiler. in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, php-extension, blenc

I am unable to create a simple test with blenc. Can anyone provide insight into why I am receiving the error below?

```
Notice: blenc_compile: unable to read stream, compiling with default compiler. in Unknown on line 0
```

php.ini

```
extension=php_blenc.dll
blenc.key_file="C:\Apache24\blenc_key"
```

blenc_myscript.php

```
echo 'Printing a secret string: Test';
```

blenc_encrypt.php

```
<?php
$source_code = file_get_contents("blenc_myscript.php");
$redistributable_key = blenc_encrypt($source_code, "blenc_myscript.phpe");
$key_file = ini_get('blenc.key_file');
file_put_contents($key_file, $redistributable_key);
?>
```

blenc_key

```
CSxNUF7YQNE5coSHexaxrEqvx4TUSTAibKoStOZifEE=
```

blenc_myscript_run.php

```
<?php
$my_source_encoded = 'blenc_myscript.phpe';
include($my_source_encoded);
?>
```

Output

```
Notice: blenc_compile: unable to read stream, compiling with default compiler. in Unknown on line 0

Notice: blenc_compile: unable to read stream, compiling with default compiler. in C:\Apache24\htdocs\blenc_myscript_run.php on line 3
 BLENC1.1.4b50476f24a47b78d81dc5e3e17d462ee8?M?]dH????fZ3?t??7n?4FT????!_????9?
```